# Selenium C# Fill Windows Security in webpage

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, windows-security

I'm encountering the "Window Security",after entering the url of the webpage. Any way to deal with this using any kind of script or selenium tools?

When I use this line the driver stop working cause of the window

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mywebpage.com/loader.aspx");
```

Can't use AutoIT to deal with this window.

Photo of the Window in question:

[Windows Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OtrS.png)

Comment: Have you tried switching to alert and then send keys on this ?

Comment: @Prany Yes, the problem is that is a "Microsoft Windows" window. So Selenium cant handle it.

Comment: Are you using C# binding ?.

Comment: No, tried to make a script for waiting this window and send keyPresses to it. But without Sucess